# How to fix intellisense with referenced netstandard1.5 library projects in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have four library projects that are all targeting the `netstandard1.5` framework. Some of them depend on the other and the intellisense is working fine under those four projects.

I am trying to use these libraries inside my ASP.NET `netcoreapp1.0` project. But when I target the `netcoreapp1.0` framework the types are not found (outlined red in visual studio). The project hower compiles and runs successfully.

As soon as I switch to the `netstandard1.5` framework inside my web api the types of the libraries are recognized and I get intellisense.

Any ideas on how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Here is the `project.json` for one of the library projects (they are almost identical):

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ],
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",

        "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.1-rc2-24027"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "HoehenSucht.Models": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-rc2-24027"
  }
}
```

And here is the `project.json` of the api:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "HoehenSucht.Framework": "1.0.0-*",
    "HoehenSucht.Models": "1.0.0-*",
    "HoehenSucht.Repositories": "1.0.0-*",
    "HoehenSucht.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "HoehenSucht.Authentication": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc2-240",
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-rc2-24027",
    "IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-rc2-240",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "HoehenSucht.API.Models": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "System.Linq": "4.1.0-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "System.Linq.Parallel": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        },
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-rc2-24027",
      },
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you restored packages after making the framework change?

Comment: I don't know how often to repeat this, but don't mix RC1 and RC2 packages!!!! `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"`

Comment: I removed the package but still get the same "error". Also did a clean rebuild afterwards.
Also did a `dotnet restore` in the solution root and project root.

Comment: Ah...
I figured it out. It was a resharper thing. Resharper does not seem to support `.net core` yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper is the problem here not Visual Studio.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-kicks-off/

> Initial support of ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2, including support for tag helpers in terms of code completion, navigation, search and refactorings. At this point, ASP.NET Core web applications are supported if they’re targeting .NET Framework but are **not supported** if they’re **targeting .NET Core**. We’re looking to improve this in subsequent builds.

So if you have a library targeting `.netstandard1.5` Resharper will not correctly display intellisense information but the project will compile.

However if you add the `.netcoreapp1.0` framework as an additional framework to the `project.json` file Resharper will work and you get full intellisense support.

```
 frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ],
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",

        "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.1-rc2-24027"
      }
    },
    ".netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
 },
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this also works on VS 2017 Preview with netstandard2.0 libraries. After adding second target framework (coreapp) to csproj on netstandard2.0 library, Resharper shows all dependencies/intellisense correctly

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`
`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`