# ASP.NET Core RC2 separate models to project for cross-platform

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-rc2

I'm trying to separate the models into their own project for use in a xamarin cross-platform application using the new .net core class library. The issue i'm being presented with is:

[image: Error image]

My solution structure is as follows:

[image: Solution structure image]

My class library project.json is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net452+win81"
      ]
    },
    ".netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm referencing the class library in the web application but I'm unsure whether I've separated the models properly or not. I've tried to find a solution but because the ASP.NET Core framework is still very new there isn't much documentation or guidance on how to separate the models into it's own project. I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance on how to achieve this.

**EDIT**

Here is my web application project.json:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-Climbing.Web-d856be17-9b54-401e-98b2-4d6589fc7ff3",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
       "type": "build"
     },
     "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
       "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
       "type": "build"
     },
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
     "Climbing.Domain": "1.0.0"
   },

  "tools": {
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Likely not related to the issue, but why the hell do you have `.netcoreapp1.0` in a class library?? This target framework moniker (TFM) is just for application and shouldn't be used in Class Libraries

Comment: It fixes the Resharper intellisense bug http://stackoverflow.com/a/37617711/3603938

Comment: And also if you want to be cross-platform remove the reference to .NET Framework 4.5.1
In your project.json, delete the line  "net451": { },

Comment: Thanks. i haven't got as far as to looking into what frameworks i need to target yet, .NET Core is still very new to me! I thought i would need to target .net451 for Xamarin?

Comment: @AdamH: Should actually work according to the target platform Matrix here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Tseng!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution oddly enough it was a namespace problem that shouldn't be a issue. I'm convinced there is a bug somewhere in the underlying ASP.NET core RC2 framework although i might be wrong?

The problem arises when i change the namespace of the ApplicationUser in the class library from 'Climbing.Web.Models' to 'Climbing.Domain' - Which would be it's correct namespace. Once i changed this back to the 'Climbing.Web.Models' namespace the problem is fixed.

Edit:
Dived a little deeper and realised i hadn't updated namespaces in views where ApplicationUser was referenced. Fixed this issue by updating the imports.

Comment: The views are compiled at runtime, so that may explain it. They removed view precompilation in rc1 or rc2 until they find a new places to put it in

Answer (score 0):

Individual Project within a solution dont always have all the references you need you can add them manually like this.

- Right click on the project title.
- Go Add -> Reference
  [Screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Syk.png)
- Go Assemblies(maybe COM based on dependency) and choose the necessary dependency [Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR1xx.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. I don't think i'm missing any dependancies?

Comment: You may be using the "using" keyword that doesn't mean VS is importing it as you would expect, especially when creating new projects within a solution. At least in my experience, I had a pretty similar problem less than a month ago, and it was following this process that solved it.

Comment: The solution it seems was to change the namespace of the ApplicationUser from the class library back to it's original namespace - odd.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you don't have the correct reference from your web project to your class project (or alternatively, you are missing a `using` statement.

To reference a class project from your web project, update your web project's `project.json` and a dependency similar to the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Climing.Domain": {
        "version": "1.0.0-*",
        "target": "project"
     },
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didn't work. I've included the web application 'project.json' with my reference to the models project. I'm definitely not missing any 'using' statements as the compiler is happy and the project builds and runs.

Comment: Ah, just seen your answer below about the incorrect namespace in the views, makes sense!