# Syntax highlighting and intellisense not working .net core vs 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-core, intellisense

I am trying to work on a .net core project and syntax highlighting is not functioning properly for razor views. Is there a dev dependency or configuration property that I am missing. Intellisense is also not working properly for asp-* tags. Any suggestions? I've already tried deleting the ComponentModelCache in appdata.

[image]

Here is my project.json so you can see what packages I'm using. It seems to be project setup related, most likely a package. I am importing the tag helpers in my _ViewImports.cshtml file. I'm just not sure what's different in this project compared to default .NET Core projects. This project was started with an empty web core project.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1", 
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did it work before or not? It works fine on my side and if this issue is occurred recently, you can try to run the command: devenv /resetuserdata or /safemode in the evelated command prompt and check this issue again. If this issue persists, you can run the command: devenv /log to collect the runtime log. And upload the file (%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml) to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: You can also try to create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application-Web Application and click the 'Change Authentication', select 'Individual User Accounts' to have a test with this issue.

Comment: I have it working in another project that I added with microsofts default application. The intellisense and color coding is working properly in that project. Is it possible it's a package that I am missing? I plan on scanning and finding which dependencies I have in this "broken" project compared with the default project microsoft has.

Comment: If this intelligence and color coding only unable to work in this specific project, this issue is related to this project, you can compare them or move/copy your code to the default project to have a test. Meanwhile, there has some methods can maybe help you troubleshot this issue, you can 1: Close VS and Unload, then reload the solution, 2: Right click the solution name and select ‘Clean Solution’ 3: Close VS and delete the .suo file or the .csproj.user file of your current solution (please backup it firstly) and reopen this solution again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying different packages and searching forums and issue threads, I gave this package a shot `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final` and this seemed to do the trick. All the syntax highlighting seemed to take effect once I referenced this package.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have Resharper installed? It seems there's a problem with it and  .NET Core syntax highlighting and intellisense.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-kicks-off/

> Initial support of ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2, including support for tag helpers in terms of code completion, navigation, search and refactorings. At this point, ASP.NET Core web applications are supported if they’re targeting .NET Framework but are **not supported** if they’re **targeting .NET Core**. We’re looking to improve this in subsequent builds.

So if you have a library targeting `.netstandard1.5` Resharper will not correctly display intellisense information but the project will compile.

However if you add the `.netcoreapp1.0` framework as an additional framework to the `project.json` file Resharper will work and you get full intellisense support.

```
 frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ],
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",

        "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.1-rc2-24027"
      }
    },
    ".netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
 },
```

[How to fix intellisense with referenced netstandard1.5 library projects in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551539/how-to-fix-intellisense-with-referenced-netstandard1-5-library-projects-in-visua)

Comment: I do not have resharper installed

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted Visual Studio and seemed to work for me. I noticed the issue seem to arise when copying