# Can not implement interface in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am very new to dotnet core and I am trying to create some simple test to see how it works. 
I am creating a dotnet core project targeting framework 4.6.1
My project.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "preserveCompilationContext": true,
        "debugType": "portable",
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "frameworks": {

        "net461": {
            "dependencies": {

                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
            },
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

My startup.cs

```
namespace TestWebCore3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
            app.Run(context =>
            {
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

my Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;


namespace TestWebCore3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I did so far was similar to using dotnet new, dotnet restore but changed to project.json to target framework 4.6.1 and it seemed to work when I ran dotnet run or ran from VS2015

However, when I tried to create an interface, and a class derived from the interface, I have lost the intellisense and the project did not compile. I am new to dotnet core but I am not new to C#, but I am not sure what dependencies need to be included to get rid of the compiling error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IReceiptRepository' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    TestWebCore3    D:\....\TestWebCore3\src\TestWebCore3\Infrastructure\ReceiptRepository.cs   8
```

My Receipt class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TestWebCore3.Core
    {
        public class Receipt
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public double Amount { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
        }
}
```

My interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace TestWebCore3.Core.Interface
{
    public interface IReceiptRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Receipt> List();
        Receipt GetById(int id);
        void Update(Receipt receipt);
    }
}
```

My ReceiptRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestWebCore3.Infrastructure
{
    public class ReceiptRepository : IReceiptRepository
    {
    }
}
```

The structure of my project:

[image]

I am confused as why the compiler does not recognize my interface.

Does anyone what I did incorrectly?

Comment: Check your namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you missed including your interface namespace in your class file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestWebCore3.Core.Interface; //here


namespace TestWebCore3.Infrastructure
{
    public class ReceiptRepository : IReceiptRepository
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! namespace issue. Got it. But do you know why I lost the intellisense? Even if I included the correct namespace, I no longer have the intellisense, like I can not right click on IReceiptRepository and implement the interface but have to type it in.

Comment: Intellisense sometimes drops off for me, usually closing visual studio and reopening it fixes it.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831698/syntax-highlighting-and-intellisense-not-working-net-core-vs-2015

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have to restart VS 2015 to get the intellisense. Weird.